# Play framework 2.2.0 Print the final list of resolved dependencies

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2

I'm using Play framework 2.2.0. I want to find out what version of apache httpclient the framework is using. I want to do this because the libraries my application is dependent on depends on different versions of the httpclient.  How do I find out what is the version of httpclient Play framework resolves to in case of conflict? Is it possible to print the final list of dependent library in the classpath when you compile the application?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to deal with dependency conflicts in sbt is by looking at xml files in target/resolution-cache/reports. So just open *-compile.xml in your browser and you will be able to see all dependencies versions and much more. I recommend to use Firefox due to Chrome having problems with XSLT.

This feature is introduced in Suereth talk: http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/45081014. The fragment about your problem starts around 01:21:00.